# Database design: Value(s) per user per day

Tags: mysql, database

I'm setting up a system where for every user (1000+), I want to add a set of values every single day.

Hypotetically: 
A system where I can log when Alice and Bob woke up and what they had for dinner on the August 1st 2019 or 2024.

Any suggestions on how to best structure the database tables?

A person table with a primary person ID? 
rows: n

A date table with a primary date ID? 
rows: m

And a personDate table the person ID and date ID as foreign keys?
rows n x m

Comment: I would think just a person table with the person's attributes (names, dob, etc). And then an activity table that has a `person id` and `date` as the key would suffice. No reason for a junction table here since `date` is sort of a primary thing that doesn't need attributes (and if it does, a system wide calendar table will do the trick).

Comment: Furthermore, if you anticipate that the attributes on the activity table (what they eat for dinner, for instance) isn't going to change often (`Alice almost always has waffles for dinner every night`) then there may not need to do a record for every day for Alice, rather a slowly changing dimension table might be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I see there's no point in a seperate date table. But rather have a date field (any reason to go epoch over datetime?).

I want to run queries such as count the non-gluten allergics who ate waffles in May. Would the below be a good approach then?

Comment: `SELECT Count(d.personId) From dinnerTable d 
JOIN person p ON d.personId = p.id   
WHERE
p.isGlutenIntolerant = 0 AND d.dinner="waffles" AND  d.dateValue =???;`

Comment: Are the "set of values" the same for all the users? If yes, are they going to have big changes? Is it required to be changed, e.g. add new values, in the runtime?

Comment: @PeterHe There will likely be 5-6 values that each only have 2-4 options. So they'll be similar among all users. Then finally a free text comment which will be unique for most days/users. Most values will be generated en mass, then be changed through the UI for a small set of user/days - e.g update that 3 users ate carrots instead of pineapples for dinner on Monday.

Comment: I think that all sounds fine to me. I can't answer about the epoch vs datetime. It sounds like just a date column in that "Activity" table would suffice. I wouldn't get too complicated (with the exception being a slowly changing dimension table/logic if it's warranted).

Comment: Based on the information, you can have a Person table and Activity table. The Activity table will have a FK to Person table, a ActivityDate column, and the properties for "set of value", and a comment. If the "set" of the values (properties) need to be changed in runtime, it will become a typical EAV issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think u need a date table unless u want to use it to make specific queries easier. Such as left join against the date to see what days you are missing events. Nevertheless, I would stick to the DATE or DATETIME as the field and avoid making a separate surrogate foreign key. It won't save any space and will potentially perform worse and will be more difficult to use for the developer.

This seems simple and fine to me. I wouldn't worry too much about the performance based upon the number of elements alone. You can insert a billion records with no problem and that implies a very large site.

Just don't insert records if the event didn't happen. In other words you want your database to grow in relation to the real usage. Avoid growth based upon phantom events and you should be okay.

```
person
    person_id


action
    action_id

personAction
    person_id
    action_id
    action_datetime
```